# Saving data from controls for a faster loading of an app in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms, performance, save

I'm fairly new to c# and Windows Forms but am trying to improve my applications.
What the program does:
Loads every image from a folder to a imageList and later listView control and then show the user every image in the folder.

```
foreach (var file in directory) {
    if (Path.GetExtension(item) == ".png" || Path.GetExtension(item) == ".jpg") {
         imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(item));
         listItem.Name = item;
         listItem.SubItems.Add(item);
         listItem.ImageIndex = imageList1.Images.Count - 1;
         listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
     }
}
```

Works fine as is, however, when loading directory with more than just a few files program starts to struggle with loading quite a bit. I'm looking for ways to speed that up and one of my ideas is to somehow save `listView1` (pretty sure it's called caching) and then later simply load it instead of running the loop again. I've seen programs saving information to a seemingly unreadable file (for example XYplorer saving thumbnails to something like that) but I can't find an easy way to do it for my scenario.

Comment: If you're new to winforms, you might want to consider WPF. Is more modern and has some specific features out of the box which will help you here - like model binding - which makes it easier to update you UI while keeping your application responsive.

Comment: You might want to try a [binary serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) of your image list. That will get rid of the necessity to decode the images (which is probably the bottleneck). No promises, though. (Assuming that the image list is a plain list of images and not some UI control).